# Which is the best way to use this script in the Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I found a tutorial that covered the same functionality for Angular. Here is the code:

```
openModal() {
  document.getElementById('imgModal').style.display = "block";
 }
 closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('imgModal').style.display = "none";
 }
 plusSlides(n) {
  this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
 }
 currentSlide(n) {
  this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
 }
 showSlides(slideIndex);
 showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("img-slides") as HTMLCollectionOf < HTMLElement > ;
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("images") as HTMLCollectionOf < HTMLElement > ;
  if (n > slides.length) {
   this.slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
   this.slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  if (dots && dots.length > 0) {
   dots[this.slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
 }
}
```

It directly changes class names and styles using document. Which is the best way to implement this functionality in vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 - $refs

For getting element from DOM use [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).
If you set in HTML for an element `ref` attribute, e.g. `<button ref="myButton">` then you can change the style in the same way as in your code:
`this.$refs.myButton.style.display="none"`

Regarding loops: `ref` will help only if the elements with the same `ref` were created by `v-for`. In this case `this.$refs.<your ref>` will be an array. Example: let's say you have images displayed by `v-for` with the same `ref`:

```
<img v-for="image in images" ref="imgSlide"...>
```

Then you can manipulate `this.$refs.imgSlide` as an array:

```
this.$refs.imgSlide.forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none')
```

## Option 2 - Class and Style Bindings

Let's say you have `<img id='imgModal'...>`. You want to change `display` in 'openModal' method.
Do the folowing steps:

- Add style binding: `<img id='imgModal' :style="{ display: displayValue }"...`
- Add binding variable in data and initialize it:

```
data: {
  displayValue: 'none'
}
```

- Change the value of binding variable in the method:

```
openModal() {
  this.displayValue = 'block'
}
```

With this approach, you don't need loops to change the style for multiple elements. Changing the binding variable will affect all elements bound with it.

Read more about [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad)

Specifically for `display = "none"`: Don't hide elements by changing `display` explicitly. Use [`v-if` or `v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What about the last block with loops?

const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("img-slides") as HTMLCollectionOf < HTMLElement > ;
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("images") as HTMLCollectionOf < HTMLElement > ;
it uses this constants for later manipulation.

Comment: @NewTechLover, I updated the answer with info about loops.